# Cannot add foreign key constraint because I found no primary key constraint in one of the two tables and two tables have same primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

`INVOICE` table has its primary key as `ID_INVC` however `HS_INVOICE` table does have it too.
However when it comes to adding foreign key , I found that primary key constraint was already written for `INVOICE` and I just added my alter table script to add foreign key constraint. However I did not find primary key constraint already written for `HS_INVOICE` table. Do I need to add primary key constraint script for `HS_INVOICE` table and then add a foreign key constraint script like I did in `INVOICE` table? Only confusion is Primary key constraint is not written already for `HS_INVOICE` table so do I need to write that first?

For Invoice table , I added my script as follows:

```sql
ALTER TABLE INVOICE
ADD (
ID_ALS_ADMNSTRTR NUMBER(10,0) NULL );

COMMENT ON COLUMN INVOICE.ID_ALS_ADMNSTRTR      IS      'Primary key for the ALS Administrator that is assigned to the invoice';

Alter TABLE INVOICE
ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_INVOICE_3" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_ALS_ADMNSTRTR")
 REFERENCES "CCL"."ALS_ADMINISTRATOR" ("ID_ALS_ADMNSTRTR")ENABLE;
```

I've added a foreign key to `INVOICE` table however primary key constraint was already added as follows:

```
CONSTRAINT "PK_INVOICE" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_INVC")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 10485760 NEXT 10485760 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA01"  ENABLE
```

I do not see this part already there for HS_INVOICE table. How to proceed to write for adding foreign key constraint for this `HS_INVOICE`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that ALS_ADMIN_ID is a primary key of some other table named ALS_ADMIN and this some other column ALS_ADMIN_ID to add as foreignkey to HS_INVOICE, hence in that case, shouldn't it be 

alter table some_other_table add constraint fk_oth_inv
  foreign key (some_other_column)
  references some_other_table (some_other_column);    ??

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `ID_INVC` column exists in `HS_INVOICE` table but not as a primary key, then you first have to create it:

```
alter table hs_invoice add constraint pk_hs_inv primary key (id_invc);
```

and then add foreign key constraint (in another table) that points to it:

```
alter table some_other_table add constraint fk_oth_inv
  foreign key (some_other_column)
  references hs_invoice (id_invc);
```

---

Demo of what I said:

```
SQL> create table hs_invoice (id_invc number);

Table created.

SQL> create table some_other_table (some_other_Column number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table hs_invoice add constraint pk_hs_inv primary key (id_invc);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table some_other_table add constraint fk_oth_inv
  2    foreign key (some_other_column)
  3    references hs_invoice (id_invc);

Table altered.

SQL>
```